# Scraping to download a file handled by javascript

Tags: javascript, download, scripting, screen-scraping

I am doing some scraping and I would like to know how to download a file when there is no direct link to it.
I didn't scrape a lot in my life but most of the time, I simply had to specify the link to the document.
So the link could look like this: `href="https://mysite.test/blabla/myfile.xls"`
But here my link looks like that : `href="javascript:getFile('myfile.xls')"`

Is it specifically designed so you can't **scrape** it or are they some solutions to do it with scripting (Python or Go)?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that to download a file handled by some javascript, you have to send a post request with the same datas as if you dit it by hand on your browser.
So you will need the same cookies and request parameters as you would get if you were manually clicking on the link.
You can use the web browser inspector (F12) and play the request to find all thoses parameters.

Here is an example (keep in mind that this is specific to my problem) :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests 
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth 

//First, authenticate and get the session cookies in the authentication page
url1        = 'http://YourSiteAuthenticationPage.com'
session     = requests.Session()
response    = session.get(url1)
cookies     = session.cookies.get_dict()

//In my case, I also had to add some parts of the cookies to the URL
url1        += "blabla/download.do;sessionid=" + cookies.get("SESSIONID")
response    = session.get(url1, auth = HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'), cookies=cookies) 

//Then fill headers and datas needed (found with browser inspector on the page)
url         = "UrlOfTheFile/file.xls"
headers     = { 
    "Host":"yoursite.com",
    "Proxy-Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "98",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "Origin": "http://idc.yolo.com",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/12.0 (Windows NT 8.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "Referer": "depend on you",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "Cookie": "stillDependOnYou; secondCookie=07"
}

//These are also found with inspector in the network part
form_data   = { 
    "subAction": "onDownloadDoDis",
    "filename": "nameOfYourFile.xls"
}

//Then send the post request to the file's URL and download it
rep = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=form_data, cookies=cookies)

//Write the content to a fresh new file on your computer
file = open("test.xls",'wb')
file.write(rep.content)
file.close()
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can download file from https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1309239 . There is no link to the files here.